# Upgrading to Django 1.7. Getting error: Cannot serialize: <storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage object

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, boto, django-storage

I am trying to upgrade a django app from django 1.6.6 to 1.7 and am using python 2.7.8. When I run `python manage.py makemigrations`, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot serialize: <storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage object at 0x11116eed0>
There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
```

And here is the relevant code:

```
protected_storage = storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage(
      acl='private',
      querystring_auth=True,
      querystring_expire=3600,
    )


    class Document(models.Model):
        ...
        file = models.FileField(upload_to='media/docs/', max_length=10000, storage=protected_storage)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return "%s" % self.candidate

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('documents', args=[str(self.pk)])
```

I've read the migration docs and read about a similar issue [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22337#no1), but I've been unable to resolve this. My app uses django-storages and boto to save files onto Amazon S3. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just make a deconstructible subclass and use it instead.

```
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible


@deconstructible
class MyS3BotoStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    pass
```

Comment: `from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible`

Answer (score 7):

The basic issue here is that you are trying to use Django 1.7 with a package (`django-storages`) that doesn't appear to have been updated to work with that version yet.

Here are some excerpts from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#serializing-values) to explain what is happening:

> Migrations are just Python files containing the old definitions of your models - thus, to write them, Django must take the current state of your models and serialize them out into a file.
>
> While Django can serialize most things, there are some things that we just can’t serialize out into a valid Python representation - there’s no Python standard for how a value can be turned back into code.
>
> You can let Django serialize your own custom class instances by giving the class a deconstruct() method.

So the solution here is to give the class `storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage` a `deconstruct()` method. That will probably be as easy as applying the [`@deconstructible`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#adding-a-deconstruct-method) class decorator.

Presumably the package will incorporate this change at some point (or perhaps the master branch already has it?), but you could also just patch it yourself.

Comment: ```@deconstructible
class MyS3BotoStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    pass```

Comment: The comment about django-storages fixed it for me. I upgraded and that took care of things. In my circumstance, using @deconstructible did not.

Comment: For custom **deconstruct()** method -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953802/upgrading-from-django-1-6-to-1-7-getting-callable-is-not-serialize-when-running