# ValueError: Cannot serialize: <myproject.storage.AzureStorage object at 0x7f85185e66d0>

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to use [AzureStorage](https://github.com/pepperdeck/AzureStorage) to for connecting azure storage with django 1.7 app .

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from myproject.storage import AzureStorage

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_file = models.FileField(upload_to="files", storage=AzureStorage(container="media"))
    my_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images", storage=AzureStorage(container="media"))
```

But when I try to makemigrations I am getting :

```
ValueError: Cannot serialize: <myproject.storage.AzureStorage object at 0x7f85185e66d0>
There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
For more, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing
```

What exactly its not able to serialize ?

Comment: maybe modified_time ... try to debug it ... it is only 64 lines of code which nobody updates for 2 years :D

Comment: Adding @deconstructible to AzureStorage Class fixes this error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you checked the solution from [Upgrading to Django 1.7. Getting error: Cannot serialize: <storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648335/upgrading-to-django-1-7-getting-error-cannot-serialize-storages-backends-s3b) which was a similar question asking before. Copied the answer here for your quick reference:

> The basic issue here is that you are trying to use Django 1.7 with a
>   package (django-storages) that doesn't appear to have been updated to
>   work with that version yet.
>
> Here are some excerpts from the documentation to explain what is
>   happening:
>
> Migrations are just Python files containing the old definitions of
>   your models - thus, to write them, Django must take the current state
>   of your models and serialize them out into a file.
>
> While Django can serialize most things, there are some things that we
>   just can’t serialize out into a valid Python representation - there’s
>   no Python standard for how a value can be turned back into code.
>
> You can let Django serialize your own custom class instances by giving
>   the class a deconstruct() method.
>
> So the solution here is to give the class
>   storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage a deconstruct() method. That
>   will probably be as easy as applying the @deconstructible class
>   decorator.
>
> Presumably the package will incorporate this change at some point (or
>   perhaps the master branch already has it?), but you could also just
>   patch it yourself.

Please feel free to let us know if the solution (**use the @deconstructible class decorator from django.utils.deconstruct to add the deconstruct() method**) does not work for you.