# django storages FTP NotImplementedError (exists method)

Tags: python, django, ftp, django-storage

I'm trying to save files in a FTP server. At first, I had [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985183/django-file-upload-with-ftp-backend) and that link was useful as minimal example too. It worked for me locally, but after I deployed it on heroku, I don't know what I changed but it stopped working and is throwing this error:

## NotImplementedError at /app/new-prof

### subclasses of Storage must provide an exists() method

[Here is the ftp.py code](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/master/storages/backends/ftp.py), an exists method is on line ~200. Useful code (if more needed, say):

### settings.py

```
Installed Applications:
[...
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'directorio.apps.myapp',
 'django_cleanup',
 'storages']

FTP_USER = os.environ['FTP_USER']
FTP_PASS = os.environ['FTP_PASS']
FTP_PORT = os.environ['FTP_PORT']
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.ftp.FTPStorage'
FTP_STORAGE_LOCATION = 'ftp://' + FTP_USER + ':' + FTP_PASS + '@<server>:' + FTP_PORT
```

### models.py

```
from app.ftp import FTPStorage
fs = FTPStorage()

def upload_path_handler(instance, filename): 
     return "{id_p}/{f}".format(id_p=instance.id, f=filename)

class Professor(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
  foto = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path_handler, null=True, blank=True, storage=fs)
  cv = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_path_handler, null=True, blank=True, storage=fs)
```

### forms.py

```
class ProfessorForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
      model = Professor
      exclude = ['name']
```

### views.py

```
def nuevo_profesor(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    pform = ProfessorForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if pform.is_valid():
        new_prof = pform.save()

        return redirect('app:professor', new_prof.id)
```

## Traceback

> NotImplementedError
>
> subclasses of Storage must provide an exists() method
>
> Request Method:    POST
>
> Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>
> Django Version:    1.9.2
>
> Exception Type:    NotImplementedError
>
> Exception Value:   subclasses of Storage must provide an exists() method
>
> Exception Location:    C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py in exists, line 130
>
> Python Executable:     C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepenv\Scripts\python.exe
>
> Python Version:    3.4.3
>
> Django Version: 1.9.2

### Full Traceback

> File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
>     149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
>     147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepvenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
>     23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepvenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
>     23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> **File "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Cosas\directorio\iep\directorio\views.py" in new_prof
>     305.             new_prof = pform.save()**
>
> **File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepvenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in save
>     451.             self.instance.save()**
>
> File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
>     700.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
>
> File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
>     728.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
>
> File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
>     812.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
>
> File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
>     851.                                using=using, raw=raw)
>
> File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
>     122.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
>     1039.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
>
> File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
>     1059.             for sql, params in self.as_sql():
>
> File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in as_sql
>     1019.                 for obj in self.query.objs
>
> File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in 
>     1019.                 for obj in self.query.objs
>
> File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in 
>     1018.                 [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
>
> File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in pre_save_val
>     968.         return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
>
> File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in pre_save
>     311.             file.save(file.name, file, save=False)
>
> File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in save
>     93.             self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
>
> File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py" in save
>     53.             name = self.get_available_name(name, max_length=max_length)
>
> File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py" in get_available_name
>     89.         while self.exists(name) or (max_length and len(name) > max_length):
>
> File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\iepvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py" in exists
>     130.         raise NotImplementedError('subclasses of Storage must provide an exists() method')
>
> Exception Type: NotImplementedError at /
>   Exception Value: subclasses of Storage must provide an exists() method

Any thoughts? Or could you suggest me other ways to do it?

Comment: I haven't explained correctly, it stopped working on dev too. I'll edit it. Anyway I've checked that they are running the same version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

[Due to an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31093681/valueerror-cannot-serialize-myproject-storage-azurestorage-object-at-0x7f8518), I added a @deconstructible class decorator in ftp.py, and I wasn't adding it correctly. I added [the example function explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648335/upgrading-to-django-1-7-getting-error-cannot-serialize-storages-backends-s3b) at the end of the code, but the decorator **must** be written just before the 'class FTPStorage(Storage)', (line 31 in the ftp.py I link in the original post).